Enable USB debugging from recovery mode on phone with unresponsive screen, stock recovery, not rooted, adb not connecting
First of all, I know there are already tens of similar questions, but none seem to be my exact scenario. And every solution gets me stuck because something does not line up with my case.
I have a Samsung A70 phone that I'm trying to recover data from after the screen stopped responding to touches. Eveything else works.
I want to be able to project the phone to my laptop and control it using some app or scrpy. However, USB debugging or developer mode was never enabled from settings and now I can't access the settings to enable it.
I managed to boot the device into recovery. It was never flashed with any custom OS or custom recovery. I saw some posts suggesting I can use adb commands to enable USB debugging. However, when I connect the device via a USB cable to my laptop, the device shows up in Device Manager, but adb devices does show it. When I go into recovery mode, the device no longer shows up in Device Manager and adb devices still doesn't work. The only way that seems to make adb devices show it is when I put the device into sideload mode. But I don't think that is helpful, cause I don't want to flash any custom ROM as my ultimate target is to recover the data from the phone.
Also, if relevant, the phone is not blocked, it does not have a password or PIN.
I'm stuck. What can I do?

You are probably going at this the wrong way... Have you tried using a mouse? Not sure on this device, but you might have to connect it to a powered hub and then connect the mouse to that, or you might be able to use a USB-C to A adapter and connect the mouse directly, then you can manipulate the screen. Modern Android devices have this stuff pretty locked down, without interaction with the screen it is unlikely you will achieve what you are looking for.

I don't have an OTG cable. What is a powered hub?

A "powered hub" is a USB hub that uses an external power source... https://a.co/d/hjXd0Lc is an example, just connect the phone to one port and the mouse to another and use an external power supply. Otherwise a USB-C OTG cable is cheap, I see some on Amazon for only a couple dollars.

I won't buy any external hardware. This is not my phone, I'm trying to back it up for someone else

If the screen still shows an image but does not respond to touches an external mouse is the best and may be the only option. If the phone is not yourse then ask the person who owns it how much the data on the phone are worth to her/him.
